# c# declare a var as an interface. why is this possbile?

Tags: c#, interface

I can't really understand this concept.

Assuming i have this interface:

```
    public interface IValidate 
    {
       Dictionary<eValidationErrors, List<string>> ValidationMessages { get; }
     }
```

what happens when i say:

```
          var Validator = control as IValidate;
          Validator.ValidationMessages.Add(key,list);
```

What is Validator? Why can i use an interface in this way?

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Validator` is an instance of a type that implements the `IValidate` interface (or null if the `control` instance doesn't implement the `IValidate` interface).

It is helpfull to do it like this, if you're not interested in the actual or precise implementation of a certain instance, but if you want to use the features that are provided by the interface.

Think about some methods in the .NET framework itself, which take a parameter of an interface - type.  The method is not interested in the type itself; it just needs to be sure that the passed argument has certain methods/properties/etc... declared by the specified interface.

Answer (score 3):

The `as` operator converts the right hand side to `IValidate` and so `Validator` is typed as `IValidate`.

In other words your code is identical to:

```
IValidate Validator = control as IValidate;
```

Your question seems to be

> Why can I use an interface in this way?

But I can't understand why you think this code would behave any other way. Perhaps the disconnect is that you aren't yet familiar with the use of `var` in C#. If so I'm sure a quick read of the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384061.aspx) will make it all clear.

> Local variables can be given an inferred "type" of var instead of an explicit type. The var keyword instructs the compiler to infer the type of the variable from the expression on the right side of the initialization statement.

Note that there is no difference in type-safety between `var` variables and explicitly typed variables.

Comment: Hovering over `var` in the visual studio IDE will tell you this too.

Answer (score 1):

At any given moment, either Validator will hold nothing (a null value), or an instance of some type that implements IValidate, which may be used as though it were an instance of IValidate.  To use an example more akin to abstract classes, but relates to the same principles, consider the following requests:

1. If a *Vehicle* parks in this space between 6pm and 8am, Tow() it.

   Get me a new *Vehicle*.

Provided every Vehicle has a Tow() method, the type Vehicle in the first request is sufficiently descriptive to carry it out.  On the other hand, the type Vehicle in the second method is way too vague to be of use.  One wouldn't necessarily have to supply an absolutely complete description of the object one wanted, if one supplied a type which had associated default parameters.  For example, if one specified ToyotaCamry, that type might have an associated default year, color, body style, options package, etc.  On the other hand, merely saying one wants a *Vehicle* would be way too open-ended.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it as control object implements IValidate. Therefore , using var gets you the interface portion of that object into Validator.

Answer (score 0):

`var` means a type will have an implicit type. It is important to understand that the var keyword does not mean "variant" and does not indicate that the variable is loosely typed, or late-bound. It just means that the compiler determines and assigns the most appropriate type.

So if you use `var Validator = control as IValidate;` the type of Validator will be IValidate.

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces generally present a protocol for communication with an object. So with casting an object to an interface you are conforming to that protocol, and thus you can only call it's publicly declared members.